# mysqli transaction committing only some of queries

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

below is my code. when I use transaction, the transaction is committed but the first query (`$receipt_query`) is not entered into the DB, the other two are. When running the queries without transaction, all queries are run successfully. So can anyone spot the problem here?!

```
$mysqli->autocommit(false);
if(!empty($_POST['receipt'])) {
    $result = $mysqli->query("insert query 1");
    if (!$result) {
        $error = 'Some error message';      
    }                       
} 

if (!empty($_POST['payment'])) {
    $result = $mysqli->query("insert query 2");
    if (!$result) {
        $error = 'Some error message';
    }
}

if(empty($error)) {
    if($mysqli->query("query 3")) { 
        $mysqli->commit();
    } else {
        $mysqli->rollback();
    }
} else {
    $mysqli->rollback();
}
```

Doesn't transaction mean "All or None"? so how come the first one doesn't commit even though the whole transaction is committed?

Comment: Have you checked mysql error log?

Comment: I normally check within php, and there's no error in the queries as they'd trigger the `rollback` statement otherwise. I shall also look at the log though

Comment: nothing wrong in the mysql error log

Comment: Maybe your `$_POST['receipt']` is empty; because when a query commit is called it should commit all buffered queries

Comment: but I'm running the same thing with and without transaction but when with transaction only two of them inserted. without transaction, all of them

Comment: Where does the transaction start? To me it seems that mysqli->begin_transaction is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start transaction after autommit.

```
$mysqli->autocommit(false);
$mysqli->begin_transaction();
```

An surround the code with try-catch:

```
try {
    // First of all, let's begin a transaction
    $mysqli->autocommit(false);
    $mysqli->begin_transaction();

    // A set of queries
    $mysqli->query('first query');
    $mysqli->query('second query');
    $mysqli->query('third query');

    // If we arrive here, it means that no exception was thrown
    // i.e. no query has failed, and we can commit the transaction
    $mysqli->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // An exception has been thrown
    // We must rollback the transaction
    $mysqli->rollback();
}
```

Comment: `mysqli::autocommit` is an alternative to using `begin_transaction`.